# Why numpy.asarray return an array full of boolean

Tags: python, numpy, types, numpy-dtype

If I want to have an array filled whith `0` or `1` depending of the pixels value in a image, I write this :

```
image = "example.jpg"
imageOpen = Image.open(image)
bwImage = imageOpen.convert("1", dither=Image.NONE)
bw_np = numpy.asarray(bwImage)
print(type(bw_np[0, 0]))
```

Result :

```
<class 'numpy.bool_'>
```

Because of the `.convert` bilevel mode `"1"`, the array must be full of `1` and `0`. https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.convert

When I try something simpler :

```
bw_np = numpy.asarray([0, 1])
print(type(bw_np[0]))
```

Result :

```
<class 'numpy.int32'>
```

But instead of the second example, the first is full of `true` and `false`.
So Why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a nutshell : In python `True` is `1` and `False` is `0`. This should correct this weird behavior :

```
bw_np = numpy.asarray(bwImage, dtype=int)
```

Long answer : Maybe `imageOpen.convert("1", dither=Image.NONE)` prefer bool instead of int32 for a better memory management :

```
import sys
import numpy

print("Size of numpy.bool_() :", sys.getsizeof(numpy.bool_()))
print("Size of numpy.int32() :", sys.getsizeof(numpy.int32()))
```

Result :

```
Size of numpy.bool_() : 13
Size of numpy.int32() : 16
```